# jar file build traceability

Tags: file, jar, build, traceability

We use Eclipse, Maven, Subversion, Jenkins and Artifactory in our build process.  We would like an automated way of storing build information (date, version number, etc.) in the resulting jar (and war) files, so that if a customer inquires as to the source files that make up the jar (or war) files, we can easily retrieve the information.

Comment: What is the question here? What problems did you run into with this approach?

Comment: We give our customer a jar or war file. The customer asks us to give him the source code related to how we generated that jar/war file.  Can we automatically add some info inside the jar/war file to be able to know how to go back to SVN/Jenkins/Artifactory to get the source code.?